# Extending CrudRepository and still creating own implementation for custom methods with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository interface that extends CrudRepository to automatically give me all of the basic crud repository functionality.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {
}
```

Am I still able to add custom repository functions and implement this interface?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: Of course you can

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes for sure.

There is section in the official documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

The idea is to have an interface for your custom code like this:

```
interface CustomizedUserRepository {
  void someCustomMethod(User user);
}
```

Then you need an implementation that ends with Impl:

```
class CustomizedUserRepositoryImpl implements CustomizedUserRepository {

  public void someCustomMethod(User user) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}
```

And finally Spring Data Repo that extends from the custom repo:

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, CustomizedUserRepository {

  // Declare query methods here
}
```

Comment: @zapl From the documentation: "The most important part of the class name that corresponds to the fragment interface is the Impl postfix."

Comment: Oops, indeed, did not expect that to be name based. Comment removed

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thank you! One last question if you don't mind answering. What is the difference between extending CrudRepository and just Repository?

Answer (score 5):

You can also write you own queries directly in the interface if you extend from `JpaRepository<User, Long>` by using the annotation `@Query`

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {

    @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
    User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Spring doc: [Query annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)